# Why does RestKit's ManagedObjectRequestOperation with PUT not update CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, put

I have the following code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[ObjectManager sharedInstance] requestWithObject:managedObj 
method:RKRequestMethodPUT path:nil parameters:nil];
```

(there are registered request and response descriptors for that object in my ObjectManager).

I then create a `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` with that request and `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]` as my context, and enqueue the request.

After the response was successful, the model object is updated with the new data but it's not saved to CoreData. I have to call `[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] saveToPersistentStore:nil];` in the `success` block in order to get it saved.

When I make a `POST` request, the new model is created in CoreData. It just doesn't save to CoreData with PUT when I update a model.

Comment: Why aren't you using RKManagedObjectStore mainQueueManagedObjectContext? And why not use the higher level APIs?

Comment: Can you give an example for using the higher level API?

Comment: We are using RestKit with MagicalRecord so this might be why we are not using those. Anyway, we solved this by assigning the `MR_contextForCurrentThread' instead of the default context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using RestKit along with MagicalRecord. We had a confusion regarding `contextForCurrentThread` and `defaultContext`. When we migrated to use only `contextForCurrentThread`, the PUT requests worked as we wanted.